# Android tablet for development

Tags: android, tablet

Can some one please suggest what kind of a tablet should I get for testing my apps ? I've just started learning Android development and mobile web app development. I was looking at the Ainol Elf 2, Ainol Aurora 2 and Nexus 7 but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any tablet is fine. I would get the Nexus 7 though because

1. It's cheap ($200 compared to some others that are over $500).
2. It's made by Google (i.e. no UI modifications made by manufacturers like Samsung and HTC).
3. It's running the latest version of Android 4.1 Jelly Bean.

But honestly, you really can't go wrong with any of those tablets.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a little concerned about Jelly Bean's lack of Flash.

Comment: I'm no web app developer... but isn't Flash becoming a thing of the past? HTML5 seems like it's replacing Flash pretty quickly...

Comment: Either way, all of those tablets will eventually run Android 4.1 Jelly Bean so there is no point buying one of the others for that reason alone.

Comment: Thanks, And would it worth going with a dual core processor ? Not sure about that because it seems like an app should ideally work with minimum resources possible. I wouldn't mind some graphic acceleration though because I plan on making games as well.

Comment: I mean, it's important to remember that not all users have fancy devices... I have a couple really old `ldpi`, slow devices that I use to test with for this purpose. But this shouldn't prevent you from buying a nice device to test with... you'll just have to make sure you don't become careless and take for granted that you are working w/ a pretty powerful device. If you don't want to risk that, you could always buy a cheap, crappy device to use as a secondary testing unit I guess too :)